# Confusion about Constructors and properties

Tags: c#

So im doing a project with a guy and I see in His code something like this:

```
  public class Foo()
{
   private string example;

   public String Example
   {
      { get; set; }
   }

   public Foo(string exampleIn)
   {
      Example = exampleIn;
   }
}
```

and as far as i can remember Im used to this kind of code:

```
  public class Foo()
{

 public Foo(string exampleIn)
   {
      Example = exampleIn;
   }
   public String Example
   {
      { get; set; }
   }


}
```

without the private part, whats the difference of these 2 constructors?
Could i make the:

```
public String Example
       {
          { get; set; }
       }
```

to

```
 private String Example
       {
          { get; set; }
       }
```

Comment: Properties are not constructors. Public is not private. An explicit backing field is not (always) an implicit backing field. Do you know the differences between these concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at are [`Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), not constructors. The way the other person does them:

```
   private string example;

   public String Example
   {
      { get; set; }
   }
```

Make me think that he might have wanted to do something like so:

```
   private string example;

   public String Example
   {
      get {return this.example;}; set {this.example = value;}; 
   }
```

The above approach is usually used when one wants to perform extra operations such as validation on the data being passed to and fro the class itself.

To answer your question, `public` and `private` are known as [`Access Modifiers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) and essentially define from where can `classes`, `methods` and `variables` be accessed. Setting object properties to `private` is unusual since setting them as private will make them accessible only to elements from within their class, and object properties are usually used to exposed certain fields to other objects, outside your class.

Answer (score 2):

Making your property `private` would hide it from the rest of the application.  This is probably not what you want.

The first code example specifies a `private` backing field which never actually gets used.  This is probably not what you want either.

The `{ get; set; }` you're seeing is the syntax for automatically implemented properties.  This is syntactic sugar in C#.  It means the backing field is automatically generated at compile time.  When using auto-properties you don't need to defined a backing field of your own.

Also, the issues you're having here have nothing to do with your constructor.